# JPA concatenating table names for parent/child @OneToMany

Tags: jpa, openjpa

We are trying to use a basic @OneToMany relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT_MESSAGE")
public class ParentMessage {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer parentId;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentMsg",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 private List childMessages;

 public List getChildMessages() {
  return this.childMessages;
 }
 ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_MSG_USER_MAP")
public class ChildMessage {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Integer childId;

 @ManyToOne(optional=false,targetEntity=ParentMessage.class,cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
 private ParentMessage parentMsg;

 public ParentMessage getParentMsg() {
  return parentMsg;
 }
 ...
}
```

```
   ChildMessage child = new ChildMessage();
   em.getTransaction().begin();
   ParentMessage parentMessage = (ParentMessage) em.find(ParentMessage.class, parentId);
   child.setParentMsg(parentMessage);
   List list = parentMessage.getChildMessages();
   if(list == null) list = new ArrayList<ChildMessage>();
   list.add(child);
   em.getTransaction().commit();
```

We receive the following error. Why is OpenJPA concatenating the table names to `APP.PARENT_MESSAGE_CHILD_MSG_USER_MAP`? Of course that table doesn't exist.. the tables defined are `APP.PARENT_MESSAGE` and `APP.CHILD_MSG_USER_MAP`

> Caused by:
>   org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ReportingSQLException:
>   Table/View
>   'APP.PARENT_MESSAGE_CHILD_MSG_USER_MAP'
>   does not exist. {SELECT t1.CHILD_ID,
>   t1.PARENT_ID, t1.CREATED_TIME,
>   t1.USER_ID FROM
>   APP.PARENT_MESSAGE_CHILD_MSG_USER_MAP
>   t0 INNER JOIN
>   APP.CHILD_MSG_USER_MAP t1 ON
>   t0.CHILDMESSAGES_CHILD_ID =
>   t1.CHILD_ID WHERE
>   t0.PARENTMESSAGE_PARENT_ID = ?}
>   [code=30000, state=42X05]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to add a mappedBy attribute to the owning side of the relationship. This tells JPA that it is only one relatiuonship and not two different relationships. Maybe on the many side.

Comment: `@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentMsg" ...` fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the `@JoinColumn` and possibly `@JoinColumns` annotations as well on your entity relationships to tell JPA how to work out the relationship. Note you'll have to specify those fields that are already present in an entity as `insertable=false, updatable=false` since you cannot have two write-able fields with the same name in an entity.

Comment: I just tried it by adding `@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")` under ` @ManyToOne` for the Child class and still get the same exception. I updated my post above. I suspect we still have a misunderstanding of how to specify the foreign keys.

Comment: You shoudl try to also use `referencedColumnName`

Comment: And `mappedBy` as per Vincent's answer :)